# Laravel 8 - multiple where clauses must be met

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table for business and one for the employees.

I am trying to see whether a user already exists in the employee table with the same user_id and business_id, however, with my current code I am unsure how to do this.

My code:

```
if (BusinessEmployee::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_id', $business->id)) {
        dd('already in business');
    }
```

Comment: you can use `->first()` OR `->count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (BusinessEmployee::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_id', $business->id)->exists()) {
        dd('already in business');
}
```

or

```
$business = BusinessEmployee::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_id', $business->id);
        
        if($business->exists())
        {
          dd('already in business');
        }
```